# Forced graph with child nodes v7

Tags: d3.js

The graph below contains a parent node and two child nodes. Those child nodes got an separate innerSimulation to center those nodes. I want to add another parent node and link those parent nodes and also the child nodes. I doubt its an easy task, I am asking for another D3.js enthusiast, who wants to help me to build a forced graph, where each parent node could contain child nodes. Further it should be possible to link child nodes with other child nodes in the same parent as well as between different parents.

I hope somebody would be interested too. The idea is to visualize dependencies to other objects(parent nodes) as well as included services (child nodes).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html land="de">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js"></script>

    <title>Node in Node</title>
</head>
<style>
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
        background: #e6e7ee;
        margin: 0;
    }

    line {
        stroke: black;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <script>

        run();

        function run() {
            const data = {
                "id": "group1",
                "members": [
                    { "id": "member1" },
                    { "id": "member2" }
                ]
            };

            const width = window.innerWidth; // window.innerWidth;
            const height = window.innerHeight; // window.innerHeight;
            const svg = d3.select("body")
                .append('svg')
                .attr('width', width)
                .attr('height', height)
                .call(d3.zoom()
                    .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 8])
                    .on("zoom", zoomed));

            const outerNodes = [];
            const outerLinks = [];
            const innerNodes = [];
            const canvas = svg.append("g");

            const outerSimulation = d3.forceSimulation()
                .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
                .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-500))
                .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(d => d.id).distance(80).strength(1));

            const innerSimulation = d3.forceSimulation()
                .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(5))
                .force('collision', d3.forceCollide().radius(30))
                .force('center', d3.forceCenter());

            let link, node, nodeGroup;

            onLoad(data);

            function onLoad(data) {
                flatten(data);

                link = canvas.append('g')
                    .attr('class', 'links')
                    .selectAll('line')
                    .data(outerLinks)
                    .enter().append('line')
                    .attr('stroke', '#eee');

                nodeGroup = canvas.append('g')
                    .attr('class', 'nodes')
                    .selectAll('circle')
                    .data(outerNodes)
                    .enter().append('g')
                    .attr('id', d => d.id)

                    .call(d3.drag()
                        .on('start', onDragStart)
                        .on('drag', onDrag)
                        .on('end', onDragEnd)
                    );

                nodeGroup.append('circle')
                    .attr('r', 80)
                    .attr("fill", "lightgrey")
                    .attr("stroke", "white")

                innerNodes.map(member => {
                    const parent = canvas.select(`#${member.parent}`);

                    const members = parent
                        .selectAll('.member')
                        .data(member.nodes)
                        .enter()
                        .append('g')
                        .attr('class', 'member')
                        .call(d3.drag()
                            .on('start', (event, d) => {
                                if (!event.active) {
                                    innerSimulation.alphaTarget(.3).restart();
                                }
                                members.each(d => {
                                    d.fx = d.x;
                                    d.fy = d.y
                                })
                            })
                            .on('drag', function (event, d) {
                                d.fx = event.x;
                                d.fy = event.y;
                            })
                            .on('end', (event, d) => {
                                if (!event.active) {
                                    innerSimulation.alphaTarget(0).restart();
                                }
                                d.fx = d.fy = null;
                            })
                        );
                    members
                        .append('circle')
                        .attr('r', 15)
                        .attr('fill', 'orange')
                        .attr("stroke", "white")

                    innerSimulation
                        .nodes(member.nodes)
                        .on('tick', () => {
                            members.attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`);
                        });
                });

                outerSimulation
                    .nodes(outerNodes)
                    .on('tick', ticked);

                outerSimulation.force('link')
                    .links(outerLinks);
            }

            function onDragStart(event, d) {
                if (!event.active) {
                    outerSimulation.alphaTarget(0.5).restart();
                }

                nodeGroup.each(d => {
                    d.fx = d.x;
                    d.fy = d.y;
                });
            }

            function onDrag(event, d) {
                d.fx = event.x;
                d.fy = event.y;
            }

            function onDragEnd(event, d) {
                if (!event.active) {
                    outerSimulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
                }
                d.fx = null;
                d.fy = null;
            }

            function zoomed(event, d) {
                canvas.attr("transform", event.transform);
            }

            function flatten(node) {
                outerNodes.push(node);

                if (node.members) {
                    innerNodes.push({ parent: node.id, nodes: node.members });
                }
            }

            function ticked() {
                link
                    .attr('x1', d => d.source.x)
                    .attr('y1', d => d.source.y)
                    .attr('x2', d => d.target.x)
                    .attr('y2', d => d.target.y);

                nodeGroup.attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`);
            }
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is what I trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Good job on posting your whole existing code. Please add more concrete description (and pictures) of the desired result. This will make it much easier to help you.